# accessing nested member of global variable can be different

Tags: javascript

I read somewhere that accessing window.location.href is more time taking than location.href. Why it should be so? When we say "window.location.href", the JS engine search for "location" member in global object "window", the same should happen for just "location.href", here also JS engine will be searching location member in window object itself.
When looking members for both expression is same why there is time difference between them. To see the difference i ran the below code in browsers console:

```
function performance(){
    var a;
    console.time('way1');
    for(var loop = 0; loop < 100000; loop++){
        a = window.location.href;
    }
    console.timeEnd('way1');
    console.time('way2');
    for(var loop = 0; loop < 100000; loop++){
        a = location.href;
    }
    console.timeEnd('way2');
}
performance();
```

The way1 loop takes around 51ms and way2 takes 35ms approx in chrome. What would be the difference ?

Comment: one cycle doesn't make a very good perf test

Comment: I have seen various benchmarks which showed that declaring variables inside of loops affected performance. Due to repeated `var` on same variable being ignored, you are doing that in the first loop, but not in the second. I would suggest moving the declaration of `loop` up to the top so that the loops are exactly equivalent, only initializing the value to 0. These benchmarks showed that every engine did things differently, so whether it matters, or how much, will depend which browser you test in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location` is a reference to `window.location`.

Now, if you use `location.href`, the javascript engine will have to lookup at the local scope for `location`, if not found, it will check the parent scopes until reaching the global scope, and then get the `href` property of it.

If you use `window.location.href`, the engine will have to first lookup for `window` in the local scope, if not found, check the parent scopes until reaching the global scope. Once found, get the `location` property of it, and then the `href` property of `window.location`.

So, there is one more lookup step between both cases and that's why a believe there is a slight difference in the performance of both.